# How to extract the last contig in a multifasta file using awk

Tags: awk, fasta

I'm trying to extract the first and last contig of a number of multifasta files. They all have different names so I don't want to do this by a specific name but by position in the file.

I used this awk command `awk '/^>/{if(N)exit;++N;} {print;}' in.fasta` to get the first contig but I'm not sure how to get the last contig in the file.

My fasta file looks like this (but with more contigs):

> PA257_2805 MKFSEKWLRSWANPQVSHDELVARLSMVGLEVDADLPVAGAFSGVVVGEVLSTEQHPDAD  >PA257_2806  MGALTKAEIAERLYEELGLNKREAKELVELFFEEIRQALEHNEQVKLSGFGNFDLRDKRQ RPGRNPKTGEEIPITARRVVTFRPGQKLKARVEAYAGTKS

and I'd like to pull out the first and last contig in the file so they're in two separate fasta files (as they are in the original files).

Desired out put- one file with first contig in:

> `>PA257_2805 MKFSEKWLRSWANPQVSHDELVARLSMVGLEVDADLPVAGAFSGVVVGEVLSTEQHPDAD

and a second with the last contig in

> `>PA257_2806  MGALTKAEIAERLYEELGLNKREAKELVELFFEEIRQALEHNEQVKLSGFGNFDLRDKRQ RPGRNPKTGEEIPITARRVVTFRPGQKLKARVEAYAGTKS

(note in actual files there are more than 2 contigs and all have different names)

Id be grateful if anyone could help me!

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of files and desired output(s) corresponding to it(them)?

Comment: please edit your question with content of file rather than using comment for that

Comment: Sorry about that! I've edited my post now, Thanks!

Comment: please add desired output for shown file

Comment: added to original post

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format you input, output, and code as code blocks, not quoted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the last contig in the file

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
PA257_2805
MKFSEKWLRSWANPQVSHDELVARLSMVGLEVDADLPVAGAFSGVVVGEVLSTEQHPDAD
>PA257_2806
MGALTKAEIAERLYEELGLNKREAKELVELFFEEIRQALEHNEQVKLSGFGNFDLRDKRQ RPGRNPKTGEEIPITARRVVTFRPGQKLKARVEAYAGTKS
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}END{printf "%s",">" $0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
>PA257_2806
MGALTKAEIAERLYEELGLNKREAKELVELFFEEIRQALEHNEQVKLSGFGNFDLRDKRQ RPGRNPKTGEEIPITARRVVTFRPGQKLKARVEAYAGTKS
```

Explanation: I assume `>` characters does appear only at beginning of headers, I inform GNU `AWK` that `>` is row-separator (`RS`). After all lines are processed I access `$0` which denotes whole last line as-is, which I prefix with `>` and use `printf` in order to avoid appending superfluous newline (which is default output row separator). If you want to know more about `RS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Never do `printf $anything` as it'll fail if/when  the input contains printf formatting chars, do `printf "%s" $anything` instead. Also, your code will output an `>` on a line of it's own at the start of the output as it'll identify an empty record before the first `>` in the input. The OPs posted input is misleading as the first `>` makes it format as a quote then strips the `>`.

Comment: @EdMorton code fixed

Answer (score 0):

One solution without awk: not the most efficient, but easy to follow and modify. It's easier to separately handle fasta IDs than IDs+attached sequences.

Make a file of only fasta IDs. Use sed to find the `>` character and replace it with nothing. Write first ID to file. Append last ID to same file. Then restore the full sequence based on ID, using `seqtk`. `Seqtk` expects plain ID names without `>`, that's why we removed them earlier. You'll probably need to install `seqtk` for this, But if you're working with fasta files, you probably want to do that anyway.

```
grep ">" in.fasta | sed 's/>//' file > fasta_names
cat fasta_names | head -1 > names.lst
cat fasta_names | tail -1 >> names.lst
seqtk subseq in.fasta names.lst > out.fq
```